# Rotated element without padding or margin is not glued to the side

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` which I rotate inside a container. I have not been able to get the rotated `div` to "stick" to the left-most side of the container. Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qfWH8/1/) to see what I mean.

Comment: try giving the div `position:relative; left:0px;`

Comment: @Lodder: Tried that, but couldn't get it to work. If you have a working fiddle, that would be great.

Comment: A not-so-elegant solution is to give the element a negative left margin: http://jsfiddle.net/qfWH8/5/ @Kolink's answer looks like the "propper" way though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the `transform-origin` (`-webkit-transform-origin` and so on) to `top left`, and add `translateX(-100px)` after the rotiation (so like this: `transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100px)`). Otherwise you are rotating around the center point (set a background on the rotated element and you'll see).

Side-note, make sure the filter isn't applied in IE9 (use a conditional comment), because otherwise both will be applied and the result is a black box.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qfWH8/7/)